# spring data neo4j @Query by relationship type

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I need to query neo4j by relationship type

this is My Entity class

```
@NodeEntity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductRecommendation {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    String product;
    @Relationship(type = "RECOMMENDS", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    Set<ProductRecommendation> linkedProducts = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I need to find all the nodes with relationship type as "RECOMMENDS".
Is there a default findBy method?
I tried with this  and it works

```
public interface ProductRecommendationRepository extends GraphRepository<ProductRecommendation> {
    @Query("MATCH p=()-[r:RECOMMENDS]->() RETURN p")
    List<ProductRecommendation> findByRelationShipType();
}
```

however if I pass relationship type as variable, it doesn't work

```
public interface ProductRecommendationRepository extends GraphRepository<ProductRecommendation> {
    @Query("MATCH p=()-[r:{0}]->() RETURN p")
    List<ProductRecommendation> findByRelationShipType(String type);
}
```

Can someone please explain.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship type cannot be parameterised (see http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#cypher-parameters).

so you will have to go with

`public interface ProductRecommendationRepository extends GraphRepository<ProductRecommendation> {
    @Query("MATCH p=()-[r:RECOMMENDS]->() RETURN p")
    List<ProductRecommendation> findByRelationShipType();
}`

Comment: I think that could be used as workaround: `@Query("MATCH p=()-[r]->() where type(r) = {0} RETURN p;")`
 `public List<ProductRecommendation> findByRelationShipType(final String type);`